# I never enter inside the LiveDataScope inside my ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I have developed 2 functions for the login.

The first "***loginOne***" works when I use the ViewModel scope.

The other one doesn't work when I use the LiveData scope.

Do you have an idea? I want to make "***loginTwo***" work.

**API**

```java
interface LoginAPI {

    @POST("login")
    suspend fun getUser(@Body loginRequest: LoginRequest): User
}
```

**Repository**

```java
class LoginRepository(private val loginAPI: LoginAPI) {

    suspend fun getUser(loginRequest: LoginRequest) = loginAPI.getUser(loginRequest)
}
```

**ViewModel**

```java
class LoginViewModel(private val loginRepository: LoginRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private var user: LiveData<User>? = null

    fun loginOne(username: String, password: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // i can enter here and get the user :)
            val user = loginRepository.getUser(LoginRequest(username, password))
            user
        }
    }

    fun loginTwo(username: String, password: String) {
        user = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // i never enter inside.. why ?
            val user = loginRepository.getUser(LoginRequest(username, password))
            emit(user)
        }
    }

    fun getUser(): LiveData<User>? = user
}
```

**Fragment**, my viewModel is injected with Koin

```java
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

   loginViewModel.getUser()?.observe(this, Observer { user ->
       Log.d(LoginFragment::class.java.name, "User : $user ")
   })

   loginViewModel.loginOne("user","pcw123")
   loginViewModel.loginTwo("user","pcw123")
}
```

Comment: May I ask you to add scopes creation lines? It would make the view more clear.

Comment: @YaroslavOvdiienko where can I find this? :/

Comment: IDK :D This is your project. Take a look at sources, how and where do you create this `Scopes`? `liveData` & `viewModelScope `

Comment: I have just import this inside my viewModel : `import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.liveData`

Comment: You are using `viewModelScope`, not LiveDataScope to launch the coroutine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you created `Scope` in the right way. Also, that you are using appropriate `Dispatchers` to achieve wanted results.

You can additionally check if the call is being executed when you wanted to `postValue`.
Check if `Job` is still alive.

Check this [thing](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata).
Your `emmit` call looks suspicious.

> When using LiveData, you might need to calculate values asynchronously. For example, you might want to retrieve a user's preferences and serve them to your UI. In these cases, you can use the liveData builder function to call a suspend function, serving the result as a LiveData object.
>
> Each emit() call suspends the execution of the block until the LiveData value is set on the main thread.
>
> In the example below, loadUser() is a suspend function declared elsewhere. Use the liveData builder function to call loadUser() asynchronously, and then use emit() to emit the result:

```
val user: LiveData<User> = liveData {
    val data = database.loadUser() // loadUser is a suspend function.
    emit(data)
}
```

**EDIT:** `MutableLiveData` for `user` variable - resolved the issue.

Comment: @diAz https://proandroiddev.com/coroutines-with-architecture-components-4c223a51b112 this might help also

Comment: Try to create another variable of  `private var user: LiveData<User>? = null` for your second function.

Comment: More info about coroutines: https://github.com/uptechteam/android-cookbook/tree/master. Just switch branches to see all the info.

Comment: What is the difference between LiveData builder above and LiveDataScope for coroutine?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> The liveData building block serves as a structured concurrency
>   primitive between coroutines and LiveData. **The code block starts
>   executing when LiveData becomes active** and is automatically canceled
>   after a configurable timeout when the LiveData becomes inactive.

So, in your case, the 'user' liveData is already activated when you observing it from fragment. Because you called loginTwo() after liveData has been observed, the emit function will not triggered anymore. Try to call loginTwo() before observing liveData to get emit value from liveData ktx.

Comment: So this is like `viewModelScope`, but for LiveData?